# Can our current atomic clocks be used to pick up gravitational waves?

Tags: experimental-physics

A German team used ytterbium atoms to set a new record for accuracy in 2016 and is measured in 10's of trillionths of a second.  I heard the LIGO detector has a sensitivity of length equal to 1/250 times the size of a proton. Is there a number measured in time as parts of a second that would be equal to this? Reason I ask is that I am curious if 10's of trillionths of a second  would be enough to pick up a gravitational wave when time changes as the wave hits the clock.  I am thinking the LIGO is many magnitudes more sensitive but maybe an expert would know. Just curious.

Comment: The speed of light follows on the usual definition of velocity,  $v = d/t&. Plug in your values for the speed of light $v$ and the proton size fraction $d$ and the necessary time interval is only an algebraic operation or two away.

Comment: not sure I follow.  I would need the equivalent time interval of 1/250* length of proton.   The only formulas I know are special relativity but that uses space and time separately.

Comment: I apologize, I was on the wrong track... that's what I get for posting before I've eaten, when my brain is starved. What clock-based detection method do you propose for gravitational waves? Measuring a difference in elapsed time as I imagine you mean would require the wave to affect one clock but not another, I think

Comment: Yes , that's about it. It may be a foolish idea but since space and time cannot be separated when the earth "wiggles" back and forth in it's length , height and width then time should do the same thing. So a sensitive clock would click slower and then faster depending on it's orientation?  Certainly if you had two of them separated just like the LIGO then one would slow down or speed up before the other but they would not have to be connected in anyway and that would be interesting that you don't need to connect them.  Maybe you would never be able to compare them and it's a stupid idea?

Comment: I'm not certain that atomic clocks are sensitive to orientation, but honestly I have no idea on the actual design so they might be. Nevertheless, you'd have to compare the clocks in real time to notice any GW effect, and the signals would have to travel around the Earth at or below the speed that the GWs travel through the Earth... LIGO can compare datasets months after the fact with pre-sychronized clocks, but your idea relies on constantly resynchronizing in real time which world be technologically challenging, at least.

Comment: You bring interesting thoughts to the table...just as a note:  ...curious how length can be easily dealt with in the LIGO and how time presents a larger challenge.  And although space and time cannot be separated they must be fundamentally very different as can be seen when trying to compare differences with themselves.